# Dynamically creating C# Dictionary<Cottle.Value, Cottle.Value> from json using System.Text.JSON without foreach

Tags: c#, json

I’m trying to create an object of `Dictionary<Cottle.Value, Cottle.Value>` (*Cottle is a templating engine that uses it’s own type for storing keys and values to replace {key} text with values in a template*) from a json string that doesn’t have nested values so that each and any pair of json key/values gets converted to a dictionary keyvaluepair…but the best I’ve managed to do so far is create a `Dictionary<string, string>` thus leaving me with the problem of creating `Cottle.Value` from string which can actually be done by calling `Value.FromString(string)` but doing that requires going through a foreach loop, so I’m just wondering is there a more direct way to do that? TIA

P.S.

Unfortunately, I’m not using Newtonsoft to create a custom converter and may have missed the way to the same with System.Text.JSON so that could be an easiest solution if still possible but seems too complicated for a simple thing I’m trying to do…adding it to a webapi.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `Cottle.Value` implement `IEquatable<Cottle.Value>` and override `GetHashCode`? Is it a class or struct?

Comment: I’ll check now, but think it’s a struct.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, seems a class, at least by https://cottle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/page/06-api.html#value-declaration, though I think I saw intellicode, back when I was trying foreach also, show me some part of it to be a struct…

Comment: It does and it is: https://github.com/r3c/cottle/blob/9ce80a4fa078426fd5e541eecfb466ab1c8b3f5c/src/Cottle/Value.cs

Comment: I was just gonna write about that…it implements IEvaluable a custom interface which in turn does use IEquatable https://github.com/r3c/cottle/blob/9089e27fb2add74f0c3eeedc441849c942a8af05/src/Cottle/IEvaluable.cs#L5 but having not seen that in real-world use by now not sure what it does…I’ll check that if you say it’s a useful interface.

Comment: um, could it be as simple as just recasting it from dictionary<string, string>, if so I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: Casting won’t work.

Comment: Guess I’m a complete n00b when it comes to dictionaries, cause I just realized you could do inputDict.ToDictionary(item => (newClass)item.Key, item => (newClass)item.Value)…guessing that’s possible cause of IEquatable, right? Anyway, if you’d like just jot down that code above as an answer and I’ll mark it as such. Thanks again.

Comment: If the 'newClass' you're casting to is the Cottle.Value, that is possible because that class defines an implicit operator which allows you to get a proper Value object out of string, bool, int, etc. 
     public static implicit operator Value(string value)
        {
            return Value.FromString(value);
        }